# Why is form submit handler not called when calling form_set_error?

Tags: 6, forms

I want to know where in Drupal documentation it is listed that submit handlers are not called when form_set_error has been called.

I don't see it in [form_ser_error api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/6), nor in [FAPI Quickstart guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826) and [FAPI reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#disabled).

Looks like I'm missing some simple thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

submit handlers are only invoked if there are no validation errors. Calling form_set_error() results in a validation error.

From the quickstart guide that you linked:

> 1. A submit function is called only if a submit button was present and exists in the $_POST, and validation did not fail.